# Javascript debuggers (Chrome and Webstorm) always break at non-existent breakpoint

Tags: javascript, debugging, breakpoints

The Chrome dev tools and Webstorm javascript debuggers always break at the line:

```
if(typeof qmLog !== "undefined"){
```

in the javascript file below even though there is no breakpoint there.

Do you have any idea how to avoid this breaking

```js
String.prototype.toCamelCase = function() {
  return this.replace(/(\_[a-z])/g, function($1) {
    return $1.toUpperCase().replace('_', '');
  });
};
var qm = {
  /// lots of stuff here... 
};
if (typeof qmLog !== "undefined") {
  qm.qmLog = qmLog;
  qmLog.qm = qm;
}
//if(typeof window !== "undefined" && typeof window.qmLog === "undefined"){window.qmLog = qm.qmLog;}  // Need to use qm.qmLog so it's available in node.js modules
if (typeof nlp !== "undefined") {
  qm.nlp = nlp;
}
if (typeof Quantimodo !== "undefined") {
  qm.Quantimodo = Quantimodo;
}
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  window.qm = qm;
  qm.urlHelper.redirectToHttpsIfNecessary();
} else {
  module.exports = qm;
}
```

Comment: Does it really say "Stopped at breakpoint" in the DevTools debugger?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. It only stops at `qm.urlHelper.redirectToHttpsIfNecessary();` because there's no `qm.urlHelper` in the snippet.

Comment: Thanks for trying it, @Barmar!  Indeed it does say it's stopped and I can click to continue, but it's just inconvenient to have to click to continue every time I try to debug.  Which is a lot, because I manufacture many bugs.

Comment: I guess this can be classified as a Heisenbug.

Comment: What I suspect is that you had a breakpoint set in a previous version of the code. Breakpoints are persistent, and associated with a line number. If you revise the code, the breakpoint will still trigger on the same line number, even if the code there has changed. You should see the breakpoint listed in the sidebar, as indicated in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

In the `Source` tab of the JavaScript console, look for set breakpoints over in the right hand side. If there are any, `Ctrl` + `Click` on one of them and select `Remove all breakpoints`

[image]